# Shibboleth return url does not work over subdirectory?

Tags: single-sign-on, shibboleth

We are trying to install Shibboleth for the first time and we got everything working perfectly when applying single sign for a website over a top level domain, but not under a sub directory.

Here is our Apache virtual host config file which works perfectly:

```
  <VirtualHost *:443>

    ... some other settings
    <Location />
        AuthType shibboleth
        Require shibboleth
        ShibRequireSession On
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

With this configuration, we can do this:

**SCENARIO A**

1. Go to `https://myawesomewebsite.com/secure` in my web browser
2. My web browser redirects me to my single sign on service at `https://somesinglesignon.com/authenticate`
3. I type in my username and password at `https://somesinglesignon.com/authenticate` and press submit
4. The server sends me back to `https://myawesomewebsite.com/secure`

Everything above worked perfectly.

Now I'm going to modify my virtual host file such that `<Location />` becomes `<Location /secure>`.  So my virtualhost file looks like this now:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ... some other settings
    <Location /secure>
        AuthType shibboleth
        Require shibboleth
        ShibRequireSession On
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I try to repeat the steps 1 to 4, instead I get this:

**SCENARIO B**

1. Go to `https://myawesomewebsite.com/secure` in my web browser
2. My web browser redirects me to my single sign on service at `https://somesinglesignon.com/authenticate`
3. I type in my username and password at `https://somesinglesignon.com/authenticate` and press submit
4. The server sends me back to `https://myawesomewebsite.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST`

Why is step 4 Scenario A different from step 4 in Scenario B?  How do I make A.4 the same as B.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    <Location />
            AuthType shibboleth
            require shibboleth

            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>

    <Location /secure>
            AuthType shibboleth
            ShibRequireSession On
            ShibUseHeaders On
            require valid-user
    </Location>

#<Location /secure>
#    AuthType shibboleth
#    Require shibboleth
#    ShibRequireSession On
#    Order allow,deny
#    Allow from all
#</Location>
```

I found this to be helpful: http://shibboleth.1660669.n2.nabble.com/Protect-single-sub-directory-Moodle-with-SP-reverse-proxy-td6590009.html